# using kannel post-url but empty php $_POST

Tags: php, kannel

I'm using kannel 1.4.3 and using sms service like below

```
group = sms-service
keyword = default
# keyword-regex = .*
catch-all = yes
max-messages = 0
post-url = "http://127.0.0.1/sms.php?phone=%p&text=%a&first_keyword=%k&second_keyword=%s&words=%r&binary_message=%b&time=%t&unix_time=%T&sms_id=%I&dr=%d&dr_url=%R&meta_data=%D&dr_smsc_reply=%A&message_coding=%c&message_class=%m&message_waiting_indicator=%m&message_charset=%C&udh=%u&xser0cfield=%B&account_identifier=%o&data_coding_schema=%O&smsc_originating_message=%f"
```

here is sms.php script

```
<?php
    require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/send.php";
    echo "Ting..\n";
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? ($_POST['phone']."\n"):"??";
    $text = isset($_POST['text']) ? ($_POST['text']."\n"):"??";

    $username = "tester";
    $password = "foobar";
    $to = $_POST['phone'];
    //$text = "Nomor anda adalah : $to";
    //$url = "http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&to=".$to."&text=".urlencode($text);
    //
    //$result = getCURL($url);

    $fh = fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/debug.txt","a");

    fwrite($fh,
        print_r(array(
            'method'=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
            'data'=>print_r($_REQUEST,true),
            'header'=>print_r(getallheaders(), 1)
        ),true)
    );
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

the problem is when i send message, **all parameters received as $_GET, not $_POST** even request_method value is POST

how i can retrieve all parameters like phone, text, keyword, etc using $_POST? not $_GET?

output example :

```
Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [data] => Array
(
    [phone] => +6281210*****628
    [text] => babi pake manjat pohon
    [first_keyword] => babi
    [second_keyword] => pake
    [words] => manjat pohon
    [binary_message] => babi pake manjat pohon
    [time] => 2012-10-09 10:05:49
    [unix_time] => 1349777149
    [sms_id] => 2f3e12ed-5031-4d5f-b1f2-55e3c41063a4
    [dr] => -1
    [dr_url] => %R
    [meta_data] => %D
    [dr_smsc_reply] => babi pake manjat pohon
    [message_coding] => 0
    [message_class] => -1
    [message_waiting_indicator] => -1
    [message_charset] => UTF-8
    [udh] => 
    [xser0cfield] => 
    [account_identifier] => 
    [data_coding_schema] => 00
    [smsc_originating_message] => +628*****0000
)

    [header] => Array
(
    [Host] => 127.0.0.1
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [User-Agent] => Kannel/1.4.3
    [Content-Type] => text/plain
    [X-Kannel-To] => 13013
    [X-Kannel-Time] => 2012-10-09 10:05:49
    [Date] => 2012-10-09 03:05:56
    [X-Kannel-SMSC] => at-modem
    [X-Kannel-PID] => 0
    [X-Kannel-Alt-DCS] => 0
    [X-Kannel-Coding] => 0
    [X-Kannel-Compress] => 0
    [X-Kannel-Service] => default
    [Content-Length] => 22
)

)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're setting the parameters inside the querystring not the post data, which is why you're seeing them in $_GET.

$_POST is empty because Kannel submits the data in X-Kannel-* HTTP headers rather than post fields.

See gw/smsbox.c lines 1306-1431 (v1.4.4)... they're only in the userguide in userguide.xml, so reading the source will show you which header names are used.

You don't get the ability to choose which names are used with post-url, and you don't get to choose which parameters - they're all sent on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue issue ... all i used was  use PHP `$_REQUEST` instead .. so it does not matter if it is `$_GET` or `$_POST` am able process the information.

If you want to have a POST request you can try the `post-xml` option